# Firefox internals: any way to hook into visited link checking code?

Tags: firefox, plugins, firefox-addon, xpcom

I use `~/.mozilla/firefox/XXXXXX.default/chrome/userContent.css`:

```
:link, :visited { outline: 1px dotted !important; }
:link { outline-color: blue !important; }
:visited { outline-color: orange !important; }
```

to distinct visited links from non already seen.

This help do Internet research on topic - by avoiding clicks on already processed pages.

But ever SO with human meaningful/clean/readable URLs uses query parameters (like `?rq=1`in *Related* sidebar) which make already seen pages links as non-visited and waster my attention and time...

That extension point can be redefined or hooked by FF extension to mark all URL differ on query part as same?

Comment: It's a good add-on idea. Someone should make it.